# How to read TAP report from another server in Jenkins?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've setup **Jenkins** to run unit test on **NodeJS** and deploy it to another servers if the test coverage match with my condition. 
   I use AWS with *2 instances* to host Jenkins and Apps. Below is steps that I follow:

> 1. Setup Jenkins on instance 1.
> 2. Launch Jenkins and configure the build step
> 3. At build step, I ssh to instance 2.
> 4. cd to src folder at instance 2 and git pull my repository.
> 5. Run the unit test using Istanbul and export to test.TAP, now the test.TAP is placed in instance 2.
> 6. Back to Jenkins in instance 1, I configure Publish TAP result on Post-build Actions.

<-- My concerns right here is how can I get the test.tap file in instance 2 to read the report and display in Jenkin?

Please help me. 
Thank you.

Comment: can you please explain how your getting the report from istanbul? and how and where u r checking for your conditions? I am also get struck here, please guide me..

Comment: @Subburaj: I used this **babel-node ./node_modules/istanbul/lib/cli.js cover _mocha -- $(find test -name '*.js') -R spec > test.tap** to get the report. It will export 1 file called test.tap in coverage folder.

Comment: i have more test like api,jshint ,etc so i am using gulp to configure that. In jenkins once the code is pulled in jenkins machine my gulp will execute all the test. I am able to see all coverage in console, but my requirement is i have to check for coverage percent, if it satisfies that it should be copied to server. How can i accomplish this?